# Error while attempt mount /boot/efi

Tags: virtualbox

I have installed virtualbox on my ubuntu, and I have made a virtual drive for windows, and now every time I boot ubuntu it say:

```
        Error while attempt mount /boot/efi
```

Press s for skiping mounting or m for manualy recovey

and I tried to mount the /boot/efi in gpart editor but can not, and i also tried reinstalling ubuntu and kubuntu in tty by typing:

```
         sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
         sudo apt-get install --reinstall kubuntu-desktop
```

and i have tryed enter this sudo blkuuid, and then I know it is a file you have to edit whit gedit, and which one is it grub.cfg, and nothing work can some please help.

Comment: you says that i got "Unable to mount /boot/efi" then how would you able to reinstall ubuntu-desktop.

Comment: The system boot and is in by pushing s for skip mounting, and then push ctrl + alt + do runs tty, and it still says the same and no Internet.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to share my solution as I just fixed same problem for me. I am using ubuntu 14.04 x64, however native instead of booting in virtualbox.

Tl;dr:
`sudo dpkg --configure -a` solved my problem.

I tried manually booting using `mount /boot/efi` but it exited with error 32: `mount :wrong fs type, bad option,bad superblock...`
It asked me to check `dmesg | tail`
There I found that my error is because:
`FAT-fs (sda2) : IO charset iso8859-1 not found`
After googling this error I realized that my kernel does not proberly boot fat systems. Finding that another person cannot mount fat filesystems as well, and the answer to his question was to reload kernel using `sudo apt-get install linux-generic`. When I typed this command, I had an error: `dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct this problem`. So I did and it reloaded lots of settings including grub, and I saw that it can mount /boot/efi from now on either terminal and while booting ubuntu.
Just posting this if anyone has the same problem, hope it may help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open `/etc/fstab` and watch inside the UUID really matching with the `sudo blkid` command in a Terminal. In other way:

1. Do `sudo blkid` in a Terminal. See the right UUID of the /boot/efi partition.
2. Open /etc/fstab in a Editor (eg. `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`).
3. Correct the UUID of `/boot/efi` partition in `/etc/fstab` and save the file.
4. Reboot your machine and everything should go right.